# Retain only special strings with regex

Tags: python, regex

Given a python string, I would like to retain only the sub-strings that are made up of this pattern: any two characters + underscore + any four characters. For instance if I have this string `AX_45TH (23) - JK_I KL_9056` I would like to have in return only `AX_45TH` and `KL_9056`.

Other few examples of input and expected output:

input: `"12_MKTY (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6"`
output: `["12_MKTY", "YU_MKT6"]`

input: `"12_MKT (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6"`
output: `["YU_MKT6"]`

input: `"12_M (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6"`
output: `["YU_MKT6"]`

Comment: Where did you encounter problems?

Comment: @Sushanth thanks, but how about if the input is `AX_45TH (23) - JK_I89 KL_9056`. With your solution `JK_I89` is also returned.

Comment: @Brian please update your question with a few sample inputs and expected outputs

Comment: re.findall("\b\w\w_\w\w\w\w\b", x)

Comment: That of course, assumes that by "any character" you mean "any word character"

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: re - Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re).

> ```py
> >>> import re
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> pat = re.compile("[0-9A-Za-z]{2}_[0-9A-Za-z]{4}")
> >>>
> >>> for text in ["AX_45TH (23) - JK_I KL_9056", "12_MKTY (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6", "12_MKT (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6", "12_M (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6"]:
> ...     print("{0:s}: {1:}".format(text, pat.findall(text)))
> ...
> AX_45TH (23) - JK_I KL_9056: ['AX_45TH', 'KL_9056']
> 12_MKTY (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6: ['12_MKTY', 'YU_MKT6']
> 12_MKT (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6: ['YU_MKT6']
> 12_M (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6: ['YU_MKT6']
> ```

Comment: `/w` is not quite right. Your pattern will match "U__MKTY". `/w` Matches any letter, digit or *underscore*. Equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @Ian: Thanks, I was aware of that, it wasn't clearly specified in the question("*any two characters*"). Then I revisited the initial string, and according to expected output shouldn't have matched the *underscore*. Corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

- `[A-Za-z0-9]` will match any letter or digit
- {4} matches exactly four repetitions of the previous set or character

With that in mind, this will do the trick:

```
import re

my_strings = ["AX_45TH (23) - JK_I KL_9056",
             "12_MKTY (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6",
             "12_MKT (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6",
             "12_M (BLUE), RED YU_MKT6"]

matches = []
for s in my_strings:
    matches.append(re.findall(r'[A-Za-z0-9]{2}_[A-Za-z0-9]{4}', s))

print(matches)
```

outputs:

```
[['AX_45TH', 'KL_9056'], ['12_MKTY', 'YU_MKT6'], ['YU_MKT6'], ['YU_MKT6']]
```

I always use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for prototyping regular expressions.